# What is a proximity backflip?

Tags: terminology, altos-adventure

One of the missions to reach level 34 in Alto’s Adventure is to “Land a proximity backflip.”

What is a proximity backflip? How do I land one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A proximity backflip is a backflip performed while close to the ground.**

[According to iMore](https://www.imore.com/altos-adventure-tips-tricks-and-pointers-get-you-past-triple-backflip-and-more):

> The easiest way to quickly lengthen your scarf is to try for proximity backflips—**these are backflips you do close to the ground**.

The article suggests using Maya’s increased backflip speed to land proximity backflips early in the run.

> There's a great place to do a proximity backflip right at the start of the game using Maya: After the very first hill, jump right at the flat before the second bend.